# Check for consecutive value in Map?

Tags: oop, if-statement, dart, flutter, boolean

I'm creating a chat app and don't want to display the user avatar over and over if a user sends multiple messages consecutively.

The user messages are stored in a `Map`, where the newest message has the index `0`.
To check if a message at an `index` is sent by the same person as the message before, I use the following method:

```
bool _sameUser () {
  if (index > 0 && map != null && map[index + 1] != null && map[index + 1]['fromUser’] == map[index][‘fromUser’]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work for the newest message or if there are more than two messages from the same user.
How I can rewrite the conditional so it works as intended?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

After try @Marcel answer and test more I find another issue maybe cause this.

`map[index + 1] != null` is not true even when message 2 is send. Is only true after message 3 is send.

I test with conditional in function:

```
if (map[index + 1] != null) {
print('!=null');
}
```

Comment: If you are using iterative numbers (0, 1, 2, ...) as a `key` in your `Map`, you'll probably want to replace the `Map` with an `List`. Sources: [Map](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map-class.html), [List](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason your code shouldn't work for the index `0` except you test `index > 0`.
By removing that, it should work fine:

```
bool _sameUser () {
  assert(index >= 0);
  assert(map != null);
  return map[index + 1] != null && map[index + 1]['fromUser'] == map[index]['fromUser'];
}
```

Because I assumed, the `index` should never be smaller than `0` and the `map` should never be `null`, I moved some of the condition code to `assert` statements.
Also, because your `if`-expression is a boolean, you can just return it directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am try

Comment: I try but is not work. I think maybe there is issue here if index is change because new value is insert at index 0. So other element are also change? You know issue?

Comment: What exactly is displayed and what's wrong about it? If the issue is about list items not updating when new messages arrive, that's probably a state error (maybe call `setState` at appropriate times to cause the whole list to re-render?).

Comment: Thanks for reply! Issue is not just list item not update. Issue is also when update avatar is show next to wrong message. Then when new message is add it show next to other message (sometimes correct). Then when update again avatar change position again. But this issue only happen with first 2 consecutive message. If > 2 consecutive message issue is not happen with consecutive message 3, 4...So this issue make me think there is issue with way I am check index. because I am check only `[index + 1]`

Comment: But that should be correct... If there are only two messages, the old one gets an avatar because `map[index + 1] == null` for `index == 1` and the newer one doesn't because `map[index].fromUser == map[index + 1].fromUser` for `index == 0`.

Comment: Yes this should be what happen. But is not actual happen in my app. For some reason new one also get avatar (this should not happen). So message 1 and 2 get avatar. (But not message 3, 4...)

Comment: Okay, then the function you posted is not the problem. Rather, the issue lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I think is issue with function. I have update question show with conditional